Can radio act as check box, allow deselection?
Is there any formal specification that says selected radio buttons should not permit deselection other than by selecting another radio in the same group? That is, that you cannot deselect a radio by just clicking it one more time (as if it was a check box).
If so, please provide a reference.
Note I in no way advocate for such behavior (actually, quite the opposite). We had a radio group of one radio. Then we had to make it deselectable. I changed it to a check box, but my co-workers were surprised to see a check box in place of a radio they got used to. My reasoning is if the element now has to act like a check box, it should look like one (even though it is technically possible to create a deselectable radio). I am looking to back up my position with solid references.

Duplicate question: Why is it impossible to deselect HTML "radio" inputs?

@Ren no, it's not. I saw that question. I ask for a reference specifically

It is in the definition that deselection happens when another is selected in the same group – Radio Button W3C. Nobody is stopping you from applying border-radius on checkboxes to make them look like circles. What exactly are you trying to do?

@Ren We had a radio group of one radio. Then we had to make it deselectable. I changed it to a check box, but my co-workers were surprised to see a check box in place of a radio they got used to. My reasoning is if the element now has to act like a check box, it should look like one (even though it is technically possible to create a deselectable radio). I am looking to back up my position with solid references

@Ren it's not exactly a spec, it's a wiki really

Check this article, nnGroup is a widely recognized site on UX topics, so I'm sure you can find your answers here: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/

Anywhere you could use a deselectable radio button, I find an explicit "None" option (with whatever text is appropriate), is almost always clearer and more intuitive.

Old radios sometimes had a button that didn't latch down, to cancel whichever of the other buttons was pressed. I can't remember what or why. I do remember that if it was missing you could unclick-all by half-pressing any button. Analogue buttons!

{after reading the comment section between Sergey and Ren}
Theres no "formal specification" for it – but so is the entire world of UX – nothing has "FORMAL" specs to it – Design is what could be – and that keeps evolving.
I mean, ask ourselves, what is a formal definition? If a product is designed in another way, they get sued because they didn't follow W3C? NO! Users are the judge here. So we mostly compelled to follow "FAMILIARITY".
And hence, the behavior of radio buttons is largely governed by established design conventions and user experience (UX) principles rather than strict standards.
But whenever in need of well researched articles I look at nngroup.

There is no formal specification that disallows clicking on the checked radio button to uncheck it.
But the W3C pattern for an accessible radio button group states that a selection is mandatory:

Some implementations may initialize the set with all buttons in the unchecked state in order to force the user to check one of the buttons before moving past a certain point in the workflow.

So making it possible to uncheck a radio button doesn’t make sense, unless another radio button is automatically checked at the same time. For instance a default. But that is not common behavior and will surprise people.
The fact that you can start with all radio buttons unchecked is intentional to prevent users from forgetting making a choice by showing a message on validation or to overcome steering users to a certain choice.
